"Do Justice" in Latin
Following injuriam agere/facere (alicui), it was tempting to just remove the prefix in and have juriam facere but apparently this is not even a word; but from my superficial search using jus or justita instead, simply does not work.
So how to say To "do justice" (might be with to someone, but also bare)?. I think using ulciscor is okay, but perhaps it implies punishment, whereas I am rather looking for making justice in the sense of receiving the deserving reward (which might be positive). As we say "Finishing in fourth place does not do justice to her."

My intuition suggests something like hoc ei iuri est rather than hoc ei ius agit/facit, but I don't have a passage in mind to back this up.

I'd like to respectfully register my doubts that "Finishing in fourth place does not do justice to her" is a particularly outstanding specimen of good English prose.

@SebastianKoppehel, Always open to learn. In what way it could be improved? feel free to suggest a better example.

The first thing that occurs to me is (in)dignus + relative clause with subjunctive: 'she is uworthy/undeserving of being one who would finishing in fourth place' / 'she is deserving of being one who would finish in a place better than fourth.' Or maybe decet + ACI: It isn't fitting that she finish in fourth place / it's fitting that she finish in better than fourth place

@d_e Finishing in second place is something she does herself, right? I believe the expression is more properly used in instances like "Calling Cicero a successful lawyer does not do justice to his position as the foremost orator of his time" etc.

indicabo tibi o homo quid sit bonum et quid Dominus quaerat a te utique facere iudicium et diligere misericordiam et sollicitum ambulare cum Deo tuo
He hath shewed thee, O man, what is good; and what doth the LORD require of thee, but to do justly, and to love mercy, and to walk humbly with thy God?
Micah 6:8
